# jQuery Ajax loop on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

New to Ajax, however, I can't figure out what is wrong, and I assume its the Javascript. My php page is working just fine, however, with this code my login Html simply refreshes over and over with the end of the url changing to *?username=whatIenter&password=whatIenter*

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#login_form').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '/lib/login.php',
             data: $(this).serialize(),
             success: function(data)
             {
              alert("WORKED");
             }
         });
       });
      });

  </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="login_form" action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="user" name="username">

      <input type="password" id="pass" name="password">

      <button id="loginButton" class="login_submit" type="submit" >Login</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Open developers console, check errors.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var header =  {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
    };

var request = $.ajax({
        url:   '/lib/login.php'
        ,data: $(this).serialize(),
        ,headers: header
    });


request.done(function(response) {
      alert("WORKED "+response);
    });
```

The thing is, some/most API's will require you to explicitly specify the content type, before they return the "standard" HTTP response that your Javascript will read.

Resources:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210816145541/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, which jQuery version are you using?

Your code is working fine with **jQuery 3.3.1**

Always keep in mind this good practices:

1. Disable the cache on your browser while you develop

   - Each time you wanna check your site, open the browser console and then press F5
2. Javascript code always needs to stay at bottom inside **body** tag (just before **<*/body*>**)

   - This also apply in the case you put it on a separated file (recommended)
3. Set the **action** parameter on your form, this can prevent unexpected errors

   - Even if you are gonna call the same file or url